# Animated gif not working in RN 0.51

Tags: react-native, gif, fresco

I have added

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'
```

in my build.gradle file and

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl {
   public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier);
 }
```

in my proguard-rules.pro file. But still, my gif is not auto playing in the app.
I am using RN version 0.51.
Any help where I can be wrong?

Comment: You can use react-native-fast-image to play gif's in react native

Comment: app with android version 5.x is getting hard crash on using react-native-fast-image

Comment: Use android studio to find the crash or you can check their open issues on github

Comment: bor, found any solutions yet? I am to facing the same issue

Comment: nope @RishavKumar, not yet. Please update if you find any.

Comment: I am too clue less.. I don't know why it still is an issue but on all the pages in GitHub and stack overflow they are marked as resolved!! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You need to provide a width and height to the image, width: undefined, height: undefined will not work either.

```
<Image source={require('./img/fireworks.gif')} style={{flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100}} />
```